# Spring - cannot resolve test class in beans.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, junit, spring-test

I'm quite new to Spring framework so this question may look dumb a bit

I'm trying to create abstract class `Test.class` in `test.java` package and configure it with Spring `configuration.xml` file. This file is in `test.resources` package and looks like:

```
<beans>

    ... schema URLs ...

    <bean abstract="true" id="test" class="Test" />

</beans>
```

Inspection says:

> *Cannot resolve class 'Test'*

Idea politely offers me to create `Test.class`. I agreed and it has been created in `main.java` package. But it's a bit messy. I do not want it to be there.

Code of Test.class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnitClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/configuration.xml"})
public abstract class Test {

abstract void test();

}
```

What do I miss?

Comment: give it a '@Component' / '@Bean' annotation and try again

Comment: @Palcente '@Component' didn't worked, behavior remains the same. And inspection says that '@Bean' annotation is not allowed in Test.class: '@Bean' not applicable to type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned that `resource` folder matters. Initially `configuration.xml` was created in `resources` folder of `main` package, then moved to `resources` folder of `test` package. That is the reason of such behavior. After `configuration.xml` deleting, `resources` folder remarking and new `configuration.xml` creating in `resources` folder of `test` package issue was resolved.

Comment: Glad you got it to work; however, FYI: you should never create a bean for a test class. So you can just delete the bean declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Below line should be changed to point to fully qualified class name:-

```
  <bean abstract="true" id="test" class="test.java.Test" />
```

> The class attribute defines the type of the bean and uses the fully
>   qualified classname.

Quoted from [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html).

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately. I should have mentioned that I've already tried to create nested package and place Test.class there. Didn't help. The point is that Idea sees Test.class in hints when I type its name, but when I add it - cannot resolve.